# Oracle APEX: Multiple Conditions?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I wish to have a region displayed only if

```
SELECT * FROM REI_LABOUR_RATE_REQUEST
WHERE BILLING_PARTNER = :P6_FILTER_DEALER
```

returns at least one row and the element :P6_FILTER_YEAR is not NULL.
I tried this by writing:

```
SELECT * FROM REI_LABOUR_RATE_REQUEST
WHERE BILLING_PARTNER = :P6_FILTER_DEALER
AND :P6_FILTER_YEAR != NULL;
```

but that somehow never returns any row.

Comment: :P6_FILTER_YEAR is not NULL

Comment: Oh well. Will try that.

Comment: `:P6_FILTER_YEAR != NULL` will never be true.  use `:P6_FILTER_YEAR IS NOT NULL` instead.  In fact the condition is redundant here, because ` BILLING_PARTNER = :P6_FILTER_DEALER` will only be true when :P6_FILTER_YEAR is not null anyway.

Comment: @TonyAndrews how come? Doesn't null mean "No value selected"? How could it correlate?

Comment: I mean that if :P6_FILTER_DEALER is null then both `SELECT * FROM REI_LABOUR_RATE_REQUEST WHERE BILLING_PARTNER = :P6_FILTER_DEALER AND :P6_FILTER_YEAR is not NULL` and `SELECT * FROM REI_LABOUR_RATE_REQUEST WHERE BILLING_PARTNER = :P6_FILTER_DEALER` will return no rows.

Comment: Sorry, wrong location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tony Andrews says:

> :P6_FILTER_YEAR != NULL will never be true. use :P6_FILTER_YEAR IS NOT
>   NULL instead. In fact the condition is redundant here, because 
>   `BILLING_PARTNER = :P6_FILTER_DEALER` will only be true when
>   :P6_FILTER_YEAR is not null anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try having a conditional display on the region with the type being "Value of item IS NOT NULL" and P6_FILTER_DEALER as the expression.

This should work as long as the value of the item is submitted and the item has the value stored in the session.

Region Source:

```
SELECT * FROM REI_LABOUR_RATE_REQUEST
WHERE BILLING_PARTNER = :P6_FILTER_DEALER
```